# Neo4j server locks database. Why?

Tags: ruby, jruby, neo4j

I just started to discover the world of Neo4j and stumbled right into an issue, I have problems to grasp.

I installed Neo4j and started it via `bin/neo4j start`.

In the next steps I wrote a ruby script that creates new nodes, after installing jruby and the neo4j gem. Everything fine until here.

How to get started is decribed here:
http://wiki.neo4j.org/content/Getting_Started_With_Ruby

My Problem: When the server is started and I try to creates nodes, Neo4j responds that the database is locked. When I stop the server the nodes get created.

I am used to relational databases, so I don´t understand this behaviour.

When I check the Server Info via the Neo4j Webadmin Tool (`http://localhost:7474/webadmin`) the ReadOnly flag is set to false.

It seems to me that the Neo4j approach is maybe different from relational db, meaning the server could maybe have a slightly other purpose then a db server.

Thanks for any advices,
Tobias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JRuby bindings will start it's own Neo4j instance, meaning that you will end up having two database instances trying to use the same files.

The approach is somewhat different, but relational databases use it as well, for example Apache Derby. As with Neo4j, you can either embed it in your application (that is what the JRuby bindings are doing in your case) or run it as a standalone server.

So just don't start a server yourself, that should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, is this Neo4j instance only alive as long as a transaction or maybe the script is running?

Comment: As long as the script is running. So for real usage, you should start it from somewhere in your application in a way that keeps it running, as starting and shutting down a database server are quite expensive operations.

Comment: What are you using the Neo4j server for? If you just want to interact with the graphdb from ruby you don't have to have the server running. Only if you want to expose your graphdb to other clients via REST you actually need the server.

Comment: Ok, this what I meant with the other purpose. To interact with a relational db (e.g PostgreSQL), I have to start the db server, otherwise nothing will happen ;-)